# Load Form recognizer data into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-form-recognizer

I am reading a pdf file using Form recognizer. Storing it in a "result" variable/object. As per the syntax given for the Azure Databricks/pyspark in the documentation for the Formrecognizer my output is coming out like below. Instead I need to put the output into a dataframe. Each table into a separate dataframe. Please suggest on the syntax. Thanks in advance.

```
with open(formUrl, "rb") as f:
  poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document("prebuilt-layout", document =f)
  result = poller.result()

     for table_idx, table in enumerate(result.tables):
         print(
             "Table # {} has {} rows and {} columns".format(
             table_idx, table.row_count, table.column_count
             )
         )
                
         for cell in table.cells:
             print(
                 "...Cell[{}][{}] has content '{}'".format(
                 cell.row_index,
                 cell.column_index,
                 cell.content.encode("utf-8"),
                 )
             )
```

Output

```
 Table # 0 has 3 rows and 7 columns
     ...Cell[0][0] has content 'b'BIOMARKER''
     ...Cell[0][1] has content 'b'METHOD|''
     ...Cell[0][2] has content 'b'ANALYTE''
     ...Cell[0][3] has content 'b'RESULT''
     ...Cell[0][4] has content 'b'THERAPY ASSOCIATION''
     ...Cell[0][6] has content 'b'BIOMARKER LEVELE''
     ...Cell[1][0] has content 'b'''
     ...Cell[1][1] has content 'b'IHC''
     ...Cell[1][2] has content 'b'Protein''
     ...Cell[1][3] has content 'b'Negative | 0''
     ...Cell[1][4] has content 'b'LACK OF BENEFIT''
     ...Cell[1][5] has content 'b'alectinib, brigatinib''
     ...Cell[1][6] has content 'b'Level 1''
     ...Cell[2][0] has content 'b'ALK''
     ...Cell[2][1] has content 'b'Seq''
     ...Cell[2][2] has content 'b'RNA-Tumor''
     ...Cell[2][3] has content 'b'Fusion Not Detected''
     ...Cell[2][5] has content 'b'ceritinib''
     ...Cell[2][6] has content 'b'Level 1''
     ...Cell[3][1] has content 'b'''
     ...Cell[3][2] has content 'b'''
     ...Cell[3][3] has content 'b'''
     ...Cell[3][5] has content 'b'crizotinib''
     ...Cell[3][6] has content 'b'Level 1''
 Table # 1 has 3 rows and 4 columns
 ...Cell[0][0] has content 'b'''
 ...Cell[0][1] has content 'b'''
 ...Cell[0][2] has content 'b'''
 ...Cell[0][3] has content 'b'''
 ...Cell[1][0] has content 'b'NTRK1/2/3''
 ...Cell[1][1] has content 'b'Seq''
 ...Cell[1][2] has content 'b'RNA-Tumor''
 ...Cell[1][3] has content 'b'Fusion Not Detected''
 ...Cell[2][0] has content 'b'Tumor Mutational Burden''
 ...Cell[2][1] has content 'b'Seq''
 ...Cell[2][2] has content 'b'DNA-Tumor''
 ...Cell[2][3] has content 'b'High | 19 Mutations/ Mb''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to read PDF doc using **azure form recognizer** and used **azure databricks** for converting it to dataframe following are the detailed steps

->login to the subscribed Azur account in [Form Recognizer Studio - Microsoft Azure](https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/studio)  and select layout from document analysis

[image]

->Browse required Invoice pdf file and click analyze after analysis the recognizer

[image]

->I created a storage account and two containers input (storing input invoice), freg (storing output csv)

[image]

->Create Azure databricks notebook

**1. Package Installation**

```
%pip install azure.storage.blob
%pip install azure.ai.formrecognizer
```

**2. Connect to Azure Storage Container**

[image]

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container_url = "https://formrecognizerdemo070621.blob.core.windows.net/pdf-raw"
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_url)
```

**3. Enable Congitive Services**

In place of  cognitiveServicesEndpoint ,cognitiveServicesKey in code we provide the key value and endpoint of the form recognizer created

[image]

```
import requests
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

endpoint = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="formrec",key="cognitiveServicesEndpoint")
key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="formrec",key="cognitiveServicesKey")

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))
```

**4. Send files to Cognitive Services & converting to Dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

field_list = ["InvoiceId", "VendorName", "VendorAddress", "CustomerName", "CustomerAddress", "CustomerAddressRecipient", "InvoiceDate", "InvoiceTotal", "DueDate"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)

for blob in container.list_blobs():
  blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
  poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_invoices_from_url(invoice_url=blob_url)
  invoices = poller.result()
  print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
  
  for idx, invoice in enumerate(invoices):
      single_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)

      for field in field_list:
        entry = invoice.fields.get(field)
        
        if entry:
          single_df[field] = [entry.value]
          
      single_df['FileName'] = blob.name
      df = df.append(single_df)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

[image]

**5. Upload dataframe of results to Azure**

> Due to security issues I have used relevant replacement names in place of actual names StorageAccountName = Initially created stoirage account namet,
> OutputContainer  = contrainer created for storing output file,
> formreckey =key of form recognizer

```
account_name = "StorageAccountName"
account_key = "fs.azure.account.key." + account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net"


 dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://OutputContainer@StorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = "/mnt/OutputContainer",
    extra_configs = {account_key: dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "formrec", key = "formreckey")} )


df.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/OutputContainer/output.csv", index=False)
```

[image]